# mongodb aggregation to get n level category

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

i have two schemas , product and category,
category is n level

---

**product**

```
{
_id,
name,
category
}
```

always product belongs to the category, which doesn't have children

and the data

```
    [
      {
       name:test1,
       category:ObjectId(id frontEnd category)
      },
      {
       name:test2,
       category:ObjectId(id mobile category)
      }
    ]
```

**category**

```
{
name,
parentId
}
```

and the data, it is like a tree,
mobile and web is root and the frontEnd is leafe

```
[
  {
   name:web,
   parent:null
  },
  {
   name:frontEnd,
   parent:ObjectId(id web category)
  },
  {
   name:mobile,
   parent:null
  }
]
```

I want when I get product data to be like this

```
[
     {
        name:test1,
        category:{
           name:frontEnd
           parent:{
              name:web
              }
           }
        },
     {
        name:test2,
        category:{
           name:mobile
           }
     }
 ]
```

Comment: give if you can complete sample data , and the expected result

Comment: @Takis i edited it, and explain more

Answer (score 0):

Upon clarification, a recursive lookup is what OP is looking for and it can be achieved by `$graphLookup`

```js
db.product.aggregate([
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "category",
      "startWith": "$category",
      "connectFromField": "parent",
      "connectToField": "_id",
      "as": "parent"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u7P7XMPsUEW) for your reference.

Comment: thanks, but it is not good for me
maybe a category in 5 levels and another category is in 2 levels

Comment: It is possible to do recursive lookup through `$graphLookup`. You will end up getting all the parent in a single array like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u7P7XMPsUEW). I think you will still need to know the recusion depth to wrangle to the exact form of your expected output.

Comment: yes yes, i used it ,
thanks

Comment: @AnasAlazmeh updated the answer to reflect your intented recursive lookup